# use find command to display file last modified at a particular time

Tags: bash, find

I'v been googling and reading the man page but I do not see the ability for find to display a file modified at a particular time.

so I have a time stamp like "2012-09-16 08:10:01 PM".  I want to look through a directory and find a file modified at that time.

I was hopeing find can do this.

Comment: @Keyser if you read carefully the question, you would realise that `-mmin` does not really help in this case

Comment: @OpDeCirkel That's true. It does the "less than"-operation.

Comment: @casperOne Did you close the question because you don't like Linux or there is something more reasonable that i cannot see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find <DIR> -newermt '<DATE1>' \! -newermt '<DATE2>'`

for more details you can read the man page for `find`, search in it for *newerXY* option
.... `!` means not.

So the above command is interpreted as: find files in `<DIR>` that are newer than `<DATE1>` and not newer than `<DATE2>.`

Also note that some older versions of `find` do not have `-newerXY`. In that case you have to create two files with `touch` (`touch` allows you to specify a date) and use `find <DIR> -newer <your ref file > \! -newer <your ref file 2>`